# Process Javascript Object with random Keys

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

After I download my data from firebase, the returned object is an object with several child objects.

```
myObj = 
{
    "J251525" : {
        "email" : "TOM@MAIL.COM",
        "description" : "CLEAN THE HOUSE",
        "refNumber" : "J251525"
    },
    "J512912" : {
        "email" : "JAMES@MAIL.COM",
        "description " : "BRUSH HORSE",
        "refNumber" : "J512912"
    },
    "J53f512" : {
        "email" : "HARRY@MAIL.COM",
        "description " : "WASH CAR",
        "refNumber" : "J53f512"
    }
};
```

I want to breakdown this data so that I can use it to display in my thead/tbody in html similar to the following layout

[image: screen shot]

So I need to

1. Somehow create an array of ['email', 'description', 'refNumber'] from looking at myObj.
2. Loop through the object (Is that possible with object?) and create several arrays like

> ['TOM@MAIL.COM','CLEAN THE HOUSE', 'J251525']
>
> ['JAMES@MAIL.COM','BRUSH HORSE', 'J512912']
>
> ['HARRY@MAIL.COM','WASH CAR', 'J53f512']

I dont know where to start for this because normally when I deal with objects, I know the key and I didnt have to loop through anything. However in this case, I have to somehow find how many objects is inside this main object.
Also, I can not do things like myObj['J251525'] because I would not know anthing about the key J251525

Note that I am using typescript with angular 2.

Comment: You wrote down a key "description " instead of "description", you may want to edit that, if it is not on purpose.

Comment: Ask Firebase to give it to you as an array ("list").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the object to your required format you can use this:

```js
var myObj = 
{
    "J251525" : {
        "email" : "TOM@MAIL.COM",
        "description" : "CLEAN THE HOUSE",
        "refNumber" : "J251525"
    },
    "J512912" : {
        "email" : "JAMES@MAIL.COM",
        "description" : "BRUSH HORSE",
        "refNumber" : "J512912"
    },
    "J53f512" : {
        "email" : "HARRY@MAIL.COM",
        "description" : "WASH CAR",
        "refNumber" : "J53f512"
    }
};

var result = Object.keys(myObj).map(function(key) {
  return [myObj[key].email, myObj[key].description, key];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for..of` loop, `Object.entries()` to create and push values of objects to arrays within an array

```js
myObj = {
  "J251525": {
    "email": "TOM@MAIL.COM",
    "description": "CLEAN THE HOUSE",
    "refNumber": "J251525"
  },
  "J512912": {
    "email": "JAMES@MAIL.COM",
    "description ": "BRUSH HORSE",
    "refNumber": "J512912"
  },
  "J53f512": {
    "email": "HARRY@MAIL.COM",
    "description ": "WASH CAR",
    "refNumber": "J53f512"
  }
};

let arr = [];

for (let [, obj] of Object.entries(myObj)) {
  arr.push([]);
  for (let [, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    arr[arr.length - 1].push(value);
  }
};

console.log(arr)
```

---

You can alternatively substitute `Array.prototype.map()` for `for..of` loop to return same result

```
Object.entries(myObj).map(([,obj]) => Object.entries(obj).map(([,value]) => value))
```

Comment: "Property "entries" does not exist on type Object constructor" when I hover over entries where the red line is.

Comment: @user172902 See [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries) for `Object.entries()`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for(key in myObj) {
        var holder = myObj[key];
        // here you can use the object however you like
        console.log(holder.email);
        console.log(holder.description);
        console.log(holder.refNumber);
    }
```

You should not create a new object, this will be an unneeded operation, because in an ordinary js array you will have the same structure, but instead of random keys, you will have ordered integers (1,2,3 etc.), except of course if you need to have keys you know, but I do not think so.

Comment: "Cannot find name "key" when I hover over key in the for loop. The other answers worked for me cheers

Comment: There should not be a problem, could you explain further?

Comment: ah.. it looks like I needed a let before key.